# Implementing distributed tracing in Azure

Tags: azure, logging, monitoring, azure-logic-apps, distributed-tracing

We are building integrations in Azure using a combination of Logic Apps, APIs and Azure Functions. We have requirements for end-to-end tracking of transactions from source to destination, i.e distributed tracing. We need to be able to track on custom fields, such as orderId. Any advice on how to best achieve this, pointer to articles, samples, videos are highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you googled already? Them you must have found references to Azure Monitor and Application Insights etc. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a bit more research into this. I believe using Azure Monitor is the way to go as described here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics.md. What's outlined here is really good as it explains the steps required to setup Azure Monitor. Azure Monitor in combination to what's described in the following article around end-to-end correlation with custom properties should give me what I need: https://yourazurecoach.com/2018/08/05/end-to-end-correlation-across-logic-apps/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can consider using [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview).

It has both code-less and code-based mode, and can automatically track the request / dependency etc. You can also track any custom fields by using it's [built-in method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics).

And azure function is easy to integrated with application insights, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring) for more details.

For web api, you can easily use the built-in method or using code-based or code-less to monitor it.